# Mercurial - backout an old merge

Tags: mercurial

I have a branch that looks like this:

```
A->B->C->D->...->Z
     ^
1->2-^
```

where `C` is a merge from `2` and its ancestors.

I realize now that I should not have merged. I could go back to `B` and graft `D`...`Z` but that's a lot of work. Can I backout JUST `C`?

When I try to `hg backout --merge C` I get *abort: cannot backout a merge changeset*.

These changes have been pushed to the central repo and I'm not looking to modify history or anything, I just want the inverse of `2` and it's ancestors back to the common descendant with `B`.

Answer (score 13):

## Merge is public and there are public commits on this merge

Assume we have this published history of commits (top is the newest):

```
                  revZ
                   |
                  ...  
                   |
                  revD
                   |
                  revC     <- unwated merge commit (rev2 to revB)
                   |   \    
wanted branch ->  revB  rev2    <- unwanted branch
                   |     |
```

Instead, we would like to have top state as if we had this history:

```
                  revZ'
                   |
                  ...  
                   |
                  revD'
                   |       
wanted branch ->  revB  rev2    <- unwanted branch
                   |     |
```

### How to achive this (step by step)

1. Callapse the history after merge commit (revD - revZ) into one commit

   ```
   $ hg update -r revC                # Update to merge commit
   $ hg revert --all -r revZ          # revert to the newest commit
   $ hg commit -m "collapsed commits" # Create new commit (revTmp1)

                      revZ
                       |  
                      ...
                       |  
              revTmp1 revD
                    \ /
                    revC
                     |  \    
                   revB  rev2
                     |    |
   ```
2. Copy changes after merge (revTmp1) to wanted branch (revB)

   ```
   $ hg update -r revB    # Update to the last "wanted" commit before merge
   $ hg graft -r revTmp1  # Copy changes from revTmp1 (create revTmp2 commit)

                      revZ
                       |  
                      ...
                       |  
              revTmp1 revD
                    \ /
           revTmp2  revC
                 \  / \    
                revB  rev2
                  |     |
   ```
3. Create a "backout" commit

   ```
   $ hg update -r revZ                   # Update to the top commit
   $ hg revert --all -r revTmp2          # Copy state revTmp2
   $ hg commit -m "reverted revC merge"  # Create revZ' commit

                      revZ'
                       |
                      revZ
                       |  
                      ...
                       |  
              revTmp1 revD
                    \ /
           revTmp2  revC
                 \  / \    
                 revB  rev2
                  |     |
   ```
4. Clean the temporary commits

   ```
   $ hg strip revTmp1 revTmp2

                     revZ'          <- reverted revC merge
                      |  
                     revZ
                      |  
                     revD
                      |
                     revC     <- unwated merge commit (rev2 to revB)
                      |   \    
   wanted branch ->  revB  rev2    <- unwanted branch
                      |     |
   ```

Comment: @Marwin's answer notes that to merge in the branch later there will be "some issues" or "even BIG PROBLEMS".  Does the process you describe here have the same problems?

Comment: I don't see any problems with my solution.

Comment: The solution backs out properly. If I haven't misunderstood, the challenges come up when trying to re-merge the backed-out branch later on.

Answer (score 10):

A little bit late, but I had the same situation a while ago. This worked for me smoothly:

```
hg update -C -r "revision-C"
hg revert --all -r "revision-B"
hg commit -m 'UNDO blah blah whatever the merge did'
hg update -C -r "revision-Z-or-whatever-the-current-head-is"
hg merge -r "the-new-revision-created-in-step-3"
```

Basically, this is exactly what backout does.

**DISCLAIMER:** Please note however that if you later in the future want to merge the 1->2 branch again, you will most probably run into some issues. And "some issues" is a somewhat euphemestic term here. In fact, even **BIG PROBLEMS** may appear in such a case. This scenario is dangerous mainly because the problems may arise much later and totally unexpected. It is highly recommended to abandon the "1" branch completely to avoid these risks. (Also see the comments below.)

For details, see [Backout wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout#Backout_of_a_Merge_Changeset).

Comment: I used this fix, and while it did fix the immediate problem, it has also created several others.  The note in the post should not be taken lightly, and it seems there were other ramifications as well.  I do not recommend using this method...

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What are the "other ramifications"?

Comment: (1/3) A new developer got himself into a bind by accidentally merging in another feature branch rather than main. He was just trying update his branch with what was on main, I think he used "tip" instead of "default". He made several more commits and then a tester noticed some strange functionality, which is when we identified the merge mistake. I then performed the steps you laid out, which worked beautifully and all was fine for a few days. He did some more work, and merged his branch to main eventually.

Comment: (2/3) He apparently ran into several conflicts and picked multiple wrong choices when it came to "mine" or "theirs". Our regression tests showed that this merge had removed features already tested and passed.  We spent hours unwinding this mess, and had to have a meeting to discuss avoiding the mistake in the future.

Comment: (3/3) Granted, this case probably could have been avoided if the new developer asked for help with his merge back to main. In hindsight, it would have been better if I just made a patch for the changes he wanted, abandoned the branch, and started fresh.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting story. Hopefully it will help someone in the future to avoid these problems. I was curious if your problems were related to a later merge of the "corrected" branch. And indeed, they were. This is exactly what I meant by the next-to-last paragraph. Thank to your story, I edited the paragraph to emphasize this danger more explicitely.

Answer (score 2):

Use backout tool, but be aware of what you are doing:

1. Update to the merge change set (C)
2. Right click on that change set -> click *Backout*

   - After you do backout on branch, you don't need to commit it
     immediately. Better check before, if there (among changes that arose
     after chosing `Backout` option) aren't some changes from other
     branches that you don't want to back out. If so, uncheck them before
     commit.
3. Click *Commit*

   - If you would merge branch `1-2` (or "numbered branch") into branch `A-Z` now (or later), you will lose all changes from "numbered branch" before changeset `2` (including) - that's what warning in @Marvin's answer is about.
   - To avoid that, you need to propagate this backout into "numbered branch" and redo backed out changes (later steps).
4. If branch `A-Z` is not direct ancesstor of "numbered branch", then find first descendant branch between `A-Z` and `1-2` and update workbench to its tip.
5. Right click on the latest revision in `A-Z` (= backout) -> click *Merge with local*

   - If there are more branches between `A-Z` and `1-2`, repeat steps 4. and 5.
   - Don't merge anything into branch `1-2` yet.
   - **Note: Always merge any branch only into the one from which it origins!** Otherwise you risk losing some changes after future merges.
6. Update to the tip of "numbered branch".
7. Find all files (on filesystem) that were changed by backout and copy them to some temp directory.
8. Right click on the latest revision of numbered branch's ancesstor -> click *Merge with local*
9. Copy files from step #7 back to filesystem.
10. Check changes in worbench and uncheck all changes, that are not from branch `1-2` (for example changes from revisions `D` - `Z`).

    - Unfortunately this has to be checked manualy. But it's the only safe way how to correct both branches.
11. Click *commit*

**Tip:** To be really sure what files were affected by any merge, right click on that revision and click *Diff to parent*

This is basically scenario that we used today, when we find out that one branch (which was still in development) was accidentally merged into default (instead of another one, which had the same color in revisions graph :). (Both branches had pushed changes after this merge.) It might seems time-consuming, but still better than backout merge only and find numerous unexpected errors days (or weeks) later. (Own experience.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the thg backout tool.

1. Update to the merge change set (C)
2. thg backout
3. Pick which parent you want to backout (whatever the revision for (2) is) - *Note you actually pick on the dialog the parent whos changes you want to keep not backout*.
4. Click Next
5. Click Commit

This will create a new head which you will need to merge with Z or rebase on to Z.

Comment: Tom, but that won't back out 1 will it? suppose there's like 20 commits between 2 and a common ancestor with A. How do I back all those out?

Comment: It will backout the entire merge. So all the changes done on the branch that have been merged, by the merge will be backed out. If thats 20 commits then the changes made in the 20 commits will be backed out.

Comment: In the current version of TortoiseHg, `thg backout` does not work on a merge revision.

Answer (score 1):

You can rebase `D` to `Z` onto `B`. The [documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) for rebase even discusses some similar situations. This should be doable in one command.

Comment: Well kind of, my understanding is that rebase modifies history. I don't need anything as extreme, just to apply the inverse of a series of changesets.

Comment: If it's only `2` you're worried about (and you still want `1`), then you can just use `hg backout` for `2`. It should hopefully trickle down through the merge properly and you avoid backing out a merge changeset directly. (Merge changesets are a bit weird because they have two parents.)

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial does allow backing out a merge revision; however, the functionality is deprecated. The danger is that backout does nothing but perform a reverse commit; if you change your mind and want to re-add the removed merge, you can't do this by merging the branch again. (Hg will refuse to perform a merge with an ancestor of the current revision; or, if there were some other commits on the branch after the merge, it will only merge the following commits.)

The command syntax is:

`hg backout --rev MergeRevision --parent ParentRevision`

Where ParentRevision is the parent of the merge revision on the original branch (i.e. not on the merged branch); usually, this is the first parent of the merge.

The command is not available in TortoiseHg Workbench.

After performing the backout (and resolving potential conflicts), make sure to review the new revision and amend it if necessary.